# Revision page Markdown diff uses a hardcoded font stack instead of a variable

Tags: bug, dark-mode, fonts

In `primary.css` file, this should be `var(--ff-mono)` instead:

```css
.full-diff .content {
    font-family: ui-monospace, "Cascadia Mono", "Segoe UI Mono", "Liberation Mono", Menlo, Monaco, Consolas, monospace;
}
```

I also found some other hardcoded values while I was looking into this.

In `primary.css`:

- `monospace`
- `sans-serif`
- `Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif`

In `secondary.css`:

- `Arial, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif`

I tried fixing it in the Stacks repo on GitHub, but it doesn't come from there.

Comment: `var(--ff-mono);` does not work in Firefox 99 Ubuntu. See related issue: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/378261/479836